# how to push a words into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, ecmascript-6

I want to split between words but not inside the "@%5967411b349:Jean leo%" tag.

How to fix that ?

```
let title = "Hello everyone @%5967411b349:Jean leo% and @%5995006d0d:David Leong% wish you have a good day with <audi <samsung and #canon";


const formatTitle = (title) => {
    const results = []
    title.trim().split(" ").map(title => {
        if (title.indexOf("#") === 0) {
            results.push(title)
            results.push(" ")
        }
        else if (title.indexOf("<") === 0) {
            results.push(title)
            results.push(" ")
        }
        else if((title.indexOf(title)) === 0)
        {
            let userTag = title.replace(/[@%]*/g, '').split(':');
            results.push(title)
            results.push(" ")
        }
        else {
            results.push(`${title} `)
            results.push(" ")
        }
    })
    return results
};

formatTitle(title)
```

expected output : Hello everyone @Jean leo @David Leong wish you have good day with <audi <samsung and #canon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you are looking for this**

```js
let input = "Hello everyone @%5967411b349:Jean leo% and @%5995006d0d:David Leong% wish you have a good day with <audi <samsung and #canon";

const userTag = (str) => {
    str = str.replace(/\@\%(.*?):(\w+)\s+(\w+)\%/g, '@$1:$2_$3');
    let groups = str.match(/[@#<]?\w*:?\w+/g)
                    .map(item => (item.indexOf('@') > -1) ? item.replace('_', ' ') : item);
    console.log(groups);
}

userTag(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be rather confusing but regex can achieve this nicely with the replace feature.

```js
let string = "Hello everyone @%5967411b349:Jean leo% and @%5995006d0d:David Leong% wish you have a good day with <audi <samsung and #canon";

console.log(string.replace(/(@%[0-9a-z]{1,}:)([a-zA-Z\s]{1,})(%)/g, "@$2"));
```

The code would of coarse not be a final solution but possibly an idea starter.
https://regexr.com/5lns0 will demonstrate how the regex is currently working here.

Comment: This is great but can you please do this by following my code. Because I need to push something in "results.push()". what should I use insted of  title.trim().split(" ").map({....}) ?

Answer (score 1):

I've used regex to solve this issue. You can check this.

```js
let title = "Hello everyone @%5967411b349:Jean leo% and @%5995006d0d:David Leong% wish you have a good day with <audi <samsung and #canon";
title = title.replace(/@\W\w+:(\w+\s\w+)%/g, "@$1");


const titleArray = title.match(/(#?<?\w+)|(\@\w+\s\w+)/g);

console.log(titleArray);
```

Comment: This is great but can you please do this by following my code. Because I need to push something in "results.push()". what should I use insted of  title.trim().split(" ").map({....}) ?

Comment: @SilentStorm please check now, i've returned an array now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but can you please edit your regex little bit cz output would be [ ......,"good","day","with","<audi","<samsung","and","#canon"]  Thanks in advance again :)

Comment: @SilentStorm please check now. If it solves your issue then please upvote this and set this answer as accepted. That will help others to find out the solution as well.